# Using echo and grep together

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to use echo and grep statement together. I have tried most of the thing but couldn't get the exact output
as I want.

```
     aa=$(grep -A100000 "2010-03-24" log.txt|grep "ORA")
     echo "Ip-Address|Directory Name|${aa}" > output.txt
```

I am grepping date because I want all the lines after current date and then grep "ORA" from it. There are other ways but according to my log file this is most suitable way.
I am getting the output like this.

```
     10.46.162.86|ASD----Exception|2010-03-24 07 ORA-00001 - 80 -                  
     173.45.230.59 
     2010-03-24 07:00:47 ORA-00942 - 80 - 173.45.230.59
     2010-03-24 07:01:15 ORA-00001 - 80 - 173.45.230.59
     2010-03-24 07:02:17 ORA-12849 - 80 - 173.45.230.59
     2010-03-24 07:05:09 ORA-00001 - 80 - 173.45.230.59
```

The ideal output should be like

```
     10.46.162.86|ASD----Exception|2010-03-24 07 ORA-00001 - 80 -  
     173.45.230.59 
     10.46.162.86|ASD----Exception|2010-03-24 07:00:47 ORA-00942 - 80 -    
     173.45.230.59
     10.46.162.86|ASD----Exception|2010-03-24 07:01:15 ORA-00001 - 80 - 
     173.45.230.59
     10.46.162.86|ASD----Exception|2010-03-24 07:02:17 ORA-12849 - 80 - 
     173.45.230.59
     10.46.162.86|ASD----Exception|2010-03-24 07:05:09 ORA-00001 - 80 -  
     173.45.230.59
```

I am fetching ORA from log files from different directories.

Input is like

```
     2010-03-22 07:00:47 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 ORA-00001 -  
     80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en-   
     US;+rv:1.9.2.2)
     2010-03-22 07:00:47 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 GET  
     /2009/10/yep-twitter-down.ht
     2010-03-22 07:00:48 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 GET  
     /img/input-bg.jpg - 80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+ 
     (Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en-  
     US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319+Firefox/3.9.2
     2010-03-23 07:00:48 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 ORA-00001 -      
     80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en- 
     US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319+Firefox/3.9.2
     2010-03-23 07:00:48 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 GET  
     /img/topnav-about.jpg - 80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+ 
     (Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319
     2010-03-23 07:00:48 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 GET     
     /img/entry-hr.jpg - 80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+      
     (Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319+Firefox
     2010-03-23 07:00:48 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 ORA-00001 -   
     80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en-   
     US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319+Firefox/3.9.2
     2010-03-24 07:00:48 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 GET    
     /img/header-bg.jpg - 80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+    
     (Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319
     2010-03-24 07:00:48 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 GET     
     /img/bullet.gif - 80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+ 
     (Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319+Firefox
     2010-03-24 07:00:49 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 ORA-00001 -                   
     80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en- 
     US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319+Firefox/3.9.2
     2010-03-24 07:00:49 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 GET /img/bg-        
     module.jpg - 80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+  
     (Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319
     2010-03-24 07:00:50 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 ORA-00942 -      
     80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en- 
     US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319+Firefox/3.9.2
     2010-03-24 07:00:50 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 GET /img/bg-    
     sidebarul.jpg - 80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+ 
     (Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en-US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319
     2010-03-24 07:00:50 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 ORA-00001 -  
     80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en-   
     US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319+Firefox/3.9.2
     2010-03-24 07:00:51 ZZZZC941948879 RUFFLES 222.222.222.222 ORA-00942 -      
     80 - 98.88.35.133 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+9.0;+en- 
     US;+rv:1.9.2.2)+Gecko/20100319+Firefox/3.9.2
```

The problem here is when I am doing the grep operation it fetches 100 or more lines depending upon the exception and I am able to append the Ip-Address and node name to one line only.
Also, the IP-Address and node name are generated at run time.
Please do suggest a way to get the desired output.
Thanks.

Comment: Use `sed` or `awk` or `perl`, etc. to prepend your text to each line rather than just once to the start of the variable.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a sample of your input.

Comment: Do you want the user agents cut off, or were they just lost in copy-pastation of your desired output?

Comment: @Wintermute Sorry, I didn't understand what do you mean?

Comment: The ideal output you pasted is not just something prepended before matching log file lines, the user agent part is removed from them. I wanted to know whether this is intended.

Comment: @Wintermute, Yes, I do not want to make the question too big by adding unwanted part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I just *know* that special characters are going to show up in the directory names, I'd prefer awk over sed for this to avoid code injection problems:

```
grep -A100000 "2010-03-24" log.txt | awk -v prefix="IP-Address|Directory name|" '/ORA/ { print prefix $0 }' > output.txt
```

The relevant part is

```
awk -v prefix="IP-Address|Directory name|" '/ORA/ { print prefix $0 }'
```

With `-v prefix=value`, a variable named `prefix` with the given value is made known to awk, and `/ORA/ { print prefix $0 }` instructs awk to process all lines that match the regex `ORA` by printing `prefix` followed by the line (which is `$0`).

Comment: Good, though you can probably say `awk ... '/ORA/ {print ...}'` to avoid so many pipes. And if fact everything could be done in one awk, but can get a bit messy.

Comment: Yeees...the `-A` bit would make it so. If I think of an elegant way to work it in there, I'll do it; until then, I'll just put in the `/ORA/` bit. It's a good idea.

Comment: @Wintermute I tried `grep -A100000 "2010-03-24" log.txt | awk -v prefix="IP-Address|Directory name|" '/ORA/ { print prefix $0 }' > output.txt` but I don't know why it prints the same output four times.

Comment: That should only happen if `grep -A100000 "2010-03-24" log.txt | grep "ORA"` returns four equal lines. What is the output you get?

Comment: @Wintermute These are the two files one with this command `aa=$(grep -A100000 "2010-03-24" log.txt|grep "ORA")` `echo "Ip-Address|Directory Name|${aa}" > output.txt` and the other with `grep -A100000 "2010-03-24" log.txt | awk -v prefix="IP-Address|Directory name|" '/ORA/ { print prefix $0 }' > output.txt` `-rw-r--r-- 1 ACER None   9813 Mar  2 22:48 text11` `-rw-r--r-- 1 ACER None   1641 Mar  2 19:53 test11`. text11 is for the second one and the test11 is for first one.

Comment: That would make sense for very short lines or very long directories but not otherwise. Does the content of the file look okay? Do the two files have the same number of lines?

Comment: @Wintermute No, they do not have same number of lines in fact in the second one many lines are repeating(whole line).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72082/discussion-between-wintermute-and-atul329).

Answer (score 1):

@etanreisner gave you the answer.

One way:

try:

```
grep -A100000 "2010-03-24" log.txt|grep "ORA" |
while read aa
do
   echo "Ip-Address|Directory Name|${aa}"
done > output.txt
```